# copy-paste lines between tabs in vimdiff

Tags: tabs, copy-paste, vimdiff

I'm using vimdiff to see the difference between two files. I'm wondering if it is possible to copy a line from the left tab (the first file) and paste it in the second tab (the second file). Actually, I can't even seem to be able to access the second tab.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `dp` for copying the current difference block to another side, `do` for copying from another side to the current. `dp` means "put", `do` means "obtain". The current difference block is where your caret is. Beside that: offtopic.

Comment: Thank you. I also just found out that Ctrl W + Ctrl W was the shortcut to switch between tabs.

Comment: You can find some more help in `:help diff` or http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html

Comment: This seems a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/whats-the-recommended-way-of-copying-changes-with-vimdiff

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned in comments,  you can use `dp` or `do` to move the diff the cursor is on between the buffers.

You can also use the commands `:[range]diffget` and `:[range]diffput`, meaning if you've already reviewed all differences in the whole file, you can do `:1,$diffput` or `:1,$diffget` to move all diffs from or to, respectively, the current buffer.

Comment: +1 for `:diffget` which also works for several lines selected using Vim’s linewise-visual mode, unlike `do`!